# Can I prevent zipfile from creating a redundant directory when I archive multiple files?

Tags: python, python-zipfile

In Python's zipfile module, when you create a zip file with only one file, it is correctly transformed into the unzipped form. But once I add another file, it is transformed into the redundant directory, and I muse traverse one step further to obtain a file I want.

For example:

```
import zipfile
a = zipfile.ZipFile("test.zip", "w")
a.write("test.txt")
a.close()
```

This creates a file `test.zip`. When I open it, it is transformed into `test.txt`, not `test`.

But the following code is transformed into `test`, not `test.txt` and `test.csv`:

```
import zipfile
a = zipfile.ZipFile("test.zip", "w")
a.write("test.txt")
a.write("test.csv")
a.close()
```

So can I prevent zipfile from creating the directory `test`?

Comment: Actually trying your snippet, `zipfile` in Python 3.6 on Windows creates correctly a zipfile with the 2 files without a directory, tested with 7-zip. Might it be linked to the tool you're using to unzip? (I know my default tool on Linux does create by default a directory based on the zip name)

Comment: Following to this, instead of creating the file `test.zip`, try something like `demo.zip` while retaining the `test.txt` and `test.csv` file and see if the tool extract it as `demo` with the `test.*` files inside.  If that's the case, it's clearly the extraction tool creating the directory.

Comment: @Adonis Thanks and I will check. I use macOS High Sierra FYI.

Comment: There is no Python version that I know of that would act as you describe it, and just to make sure I've tried it on 2.7.11, 2.7.14, 3.5.1 and 3.6.5. Are you sure it's not down to your decompression tool which chooses to create a parent folder when decompressing archives with more than one entry at their root?

Comment: I think that if you unzip from the terminal, you can do `unzip -j` the `-j` meaning not to create a target folder